# vbscript reads File object properties, but won't delete the file

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject, wsh

Here is my (very simple) code:

```
if fs.FileExists(strPath) then
    set thisFile=fs.GetFile(strPath)
    wscript.echo thisFile.Name & " (" & thisFile.Size & ") will be deleted" 
    thisFile.Delete
end if
```

The path is correct, because I can read the file name and file size in the output. However, this is the output I'm getting:

> D:\Inetpub>cscript PDFDelete.vbs
>
> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> 131_1443_cds101711.pdf (28660) will be deleted
>
> **D:\Inetpub\PDFDelete.vbs(38, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found**

As you can see, I get the proper output on the file properties, so I know I have a valid reference to the file object, but trying to execute the Delete() method on that exact same file object produces a "File not found" error?!

It makes no sense to me. How can the file be "not found" if I just accessed its name and size properties?

**EDIT** I should have mentioned, I initially was using the code "fs.DeleteFile(strPath)" when I first got the "File Not Found" error. I changed it to the more direct "File.Delete()" method, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if fs.FileExists(strPath) then
  set thisFile=fs.GetFile(strPath)
  wscript.echo thisFile.Name & " (" & thisFile.Size & ") will be deleted" 
  fs.DeleteFile strPath
end if
```

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14055

Comment: That was actually my first batch of code, and it threw this same "File Not Found" error, so I switched to File.Delete - didn't make a difference

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue.

There was a stray line of code further down in the script that was referencing thisFile.Size, after trying to delete that file. The error was happening on that line, not on the thisFile.Delete line.

Moral of the story: make use of the On Error Resume Next/On Error Goto 0 error trapping from the start, and things get a lot clearer.

Comment: instead of hiding errors by the atrocius (global) OERN, you should pay attention to the line number in error messages.

Comment: Or maybe I could just write perfect, error-free code from the start. You know, as long as we're stating the bloody obvious ... all I was saying is that using some basic error handling, "atrocious" or otherwise, helped me pin-point the problem.